# syntax coloring in comments on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Sometimes I have code which I need to comment out so it won't bother, but I still want the color syntax highlighting.
Maybe a darker shade, but visible.
I'm using Sublime Text 3

Comment: You'll have to change the language's syntax definition to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to uncomment part of the code if you'd like to keep the syntax highlighting for a while. There's no point in changing it permanently. It'd be confusing to read the comments.

[Shortcut to comment out a block of code with sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443857/shortcut-to-comment-out-a-block-of-code-with-sublime-text)

Answer by [Randall Ma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898247/randall-ma)

> The shortcut to comment out *or* uncomment the selected text *or*
>   current line:
>
> - Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
> - Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
>
> Alternatively, use the menu: `Edit > Comment`
>
> For the block comment you may want to use:
>
> - Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
> - Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

If you'd like to change the color of the comments you should find you color scheme.

**Option 1**

Use [Package Resource Viewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)

Install it via Package Control

Then type:
`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` ->`Color Scheme - Default`

and select your theme - `Monokai.tmTheme` as example.

**Option 2**

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30786142/3964066) by [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140688/vincent)

> Editing is way simpler than advices above.
>
> 1. Go to Sublime installation folder, find there **Packages** subfolder.
> 2. Open **Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package** as a zip archive (I use Total Commander and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys).
> 3. Find there any scheme you like `*.tmTheme`, copy to HDD and edit with any XML editor.
> 4. Pack modified file back (with Total Commander just copy file to opened archive).

Comment: I can't find color scheme that way (are you using Sublime Text 3?). Not looking for shortcuts for commenting out. Didn't answer my question. Thanks for trying though

Comment: PackageResourceViewer makes you able to retrieve the data the same way as in ST2 via Packages/Color Scheme.