# How to add a formatted block comment in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

All:

I am pretty new to sublime( I am using ST2), I wonder if there is a plugin or shortcut that allow me to select text and add a formatted block comment like:

```
/**
 * This is the comment.
 *
 */
```

I only know add multiLine comment with CTRL+/, but for above, I really have no idea, any help?

Thanks

Comment: Before you get too used to ST2, I would **strongly** suggest you upgrade to [ST3](http://sublimetext.com/3). The last bugfix release of ST2 was nearly 3 years ago, while the latest development build of ST3 was released 2 days ago. ST3 has a *huge* amount of new features, improvements, and fixes over ST2. Don't worry about the "beta" label, I've been using ST3 exclusively for over 3 years now - it's definitely production-quality. Additionally, many plugins now only work with ST3, or ST2 support is no longer ongoing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the package [**DocBlockr**](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs).

Once you install this on Sublime, simply type `/**` above the method and the entire comment stub will be generated for you, including parameters and return type! See example below.

You can find instructions on how to install DocBlockr in the Github README linked above.

[image: Example image]

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

for normal block comments the answer is here

[Shortcut to comment out a block of code with sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443857/shortcut-to-comment-out-a-block-of-code-with-sublime-text)

Windows: Ctrl+Shift+/

Mac: Command ⌘+Option/Alt+/

Comment: Thanks, but that waycan only add /* and */ at the ends of selected text, I want a way to look exactly like the format in my question

Comment: oh i see, i have no idea for that, i will edit my answer maybe it could be of some help to another person.

Comment: Thanks, **Adela Chang** helps find out a plugin called DocBlockr.